# How can I run React Native code headless from the command line?

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

**I am fully aware this is an unusual question**.

My team has recently inherited a large React-Native codebase, that features an obscure bug when 10+ devices all run the app at the same time.  The app compiles and runs in Android emulator and iOS Simulator just fine; but it is a huge burden to try to spin up 10 different emulators on the same dev box and shunt the app in each emulator into a sort of automated mode to reproduce and debug the issue.

The good news is that the issue does not have to do with UI code or anything that's actually "React Native" per se.  The bad news is, the team that wrote this code has hopelessly mixed and matched networking and UX concerns in one massive monolithic mess.

What (I think) I would like to do is be able to take the metro bundle and run against a sort of mock Native Bridge sitting at the command line in Node, headless.  Further complication, each process needs to be able to access its own SQLite instance, and be able to make network calls out to the backend running in AWS.  The bundle could potentially have a different "App.js" entry point that hard-codes forcing the app state.  We do not need to see or interact with any UI, not even in screenshot form.  We do not need access to any "native" functionality
like like camera, audio, accelerometer, telephony, etc.

The best I could find so far is trying to build the app for something like React Native for Windows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/react-native-for-windows), but I'd prefer something I can do from the Ubuntu command line.

Does anybody have ideas for how something like what I have in mind could be done?